# Is there a name for the group of real matrices whose determinant is an element of $\pm 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, terminology, representation-theory

The group of matrices whose determinant is non-zero is called the "general linear group", and the group of matrices whose determinant is $1$ is called the "special linear group". In between these two extremes is the group of matrices whose determinant is an element of $\pm 1$. It would be nice if this group had a name, for pedagogical reasons, because its elements can be thought of as volume-preserving transformations that fix the origin (whereas the elements of the special linear group preserve *signed* volume). Does it?

[Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735380/is-there-a-name-for-the-group-of-complex-matrices-with-unimodular-determinant)

Comment: What about [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)?

Comment: @ryanblack, that's much more specific. You can distort a shape in a linear, volume preserving way without preserving distances. However, note the the orthogonal group is a subgroup of the group I'm interested in having a name for.

Comment: This is related to the projective linear group.  Of course, we may regard your group as $PGL \times \{-1,1\}$, but that seems an unreasonable solution to your pedagogical issue.

Comment: *semi*special linear group?  (I made up that name...)

Comment: I've seen somewhere the notation $\mathrm{SL}_n^\pm(F)$ being used.

Comment: Indeed $SL^{\pm}_n(F)$ is the name of this group on Wikipedia now.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group#SL%C2%B1(n,F)4

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought: if we wanted to, we could start referring to $|\det (A)$| as the *measure* of $A$. If this became popular enough, then the group of interest could be referred to as the "unit measure group." If we really wanted to annoy people, we could even go one step further, and rechristen the "special linear group" as the "unit determinant group."

:)

Comment: I think I will adopt this terminology, just to annoy the downvoter :)

Comment: I would avoid this sort of idea because there are a lot of complex nunbers with absolute value 1.

Comment: @MarkS., not quite sure I follow... why is that a reason to avoid it?

Comment: Because I'd expect the unit measure group to be those complex matrices whose determinants have unit length. I guess you could write something like $UM_n (\mathbb R) $, though.